# Almost everywhere differentiability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We enumerate all rational numbers on $[0,1]$ as $Q\cap [0,1]=\{r_1,r_2,...\}$

and define the function $f$ on $[0,1]$ as

$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\theta(x-r_n)$,

where,

$\theta(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$ and $\theta(x)=0$ if $x<0$. Need to show that

(1) f is differentiable a.e.

(2) $f^{'}(x)=0$ a.e.

I guess I have to show that $f(x)$ is of bounded variation function to prove part (1). It would be appreciated if you help me on this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Correct your MathJax mistakes and try to find something that you might have forgotten to mention/define.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks for reminding me. It was edited.

Comment: You have $f(x) = \sum_{r_n\le x}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}$. From here it should be easy to see that $f$ is of bounded variation. The variation is bounded by $1$.

Comment: @amsmath yes your are right. Is it true that it is differentiable as a result? How about Part (2)?

Comment: Yes. A function of BV is a.e. differentiable as it can be written as a difference of two non-decreasing functions.